how to totally override one git branch to another
My project has been considered a legacy, and I started over. Here is what I did:

I checked out develop in my current project and created my new refactor branch.

Then I did git rm * to remove all files and start over.

While working on the new branch, some changes have been made on the original develop branch and committed.


Now that I'm done with my refactor branch, how should I safely merge or rebase this branch to develop so that it completely overrides?
Here is my thought:
Option 1. Just swap branch names.
This is a simple solution, but it should be the last option because doing so in remote branches would confuse my teammates. Next time they git pull I'm not sure they would get refactor branch pulled correctly. tell me if I'm wrong.
Option 2. Merge
Option 3. Rebase
Maybe doing a rebase would mean doing git rm * on the latest commit of develop branch again which is what I want? But what would happen if I merge?

Can you tell us clearly what is the starting point and desired endpoint?

That's an odd way to start over. Is the intent to just archive develop? 1) What is your reason to use the same repository, but completely new content? 2) What do you want to do with the changes to develop?

@Schwern 1) because even though its completely new in source code, it is same project. And its repository is tied to many other tools (CI/CD) which then has to get changed along. 2) I don't need it. I'm going to re-implement it in refactor branch anyway.

It seems like that you want to maintain the version of the refactor branch regardless of what is present in develop. If you're absolutely sure that this is the case, then you could perform a merge with the ours strategy. This merge must be executed with the -s option, which simply keeps the current version, and not with the -X option, which would fall on the current version only for conflicts.

This should not be confused with the ours merge strategy, which does not even look at what the other tree contains at all. It discards everything the other tree did, declaring our history contains all that happened in it.

In your case, since there is no theirs strategy for the -s option, you need to perform a couple of merges to "trick" Git into believing that refactor's changes are already present in develop.
# making sure to be on branch refactor
git checkout refactor

# creating a temporary branch from refactor and switching to it
git checkout -b temp

# merging develop into temp and keeping only the version from temp (i.e. refactor),
# this will result in a new merge commit on temp where every commit in develop is reachable from temp
git merge -s ours develop

# switching to branch develop
git checkout develop

# fast-forward merge as "every commit in develop is already contained in temp", keeping only temp's version (i.e refactor)
git merge temp

# deleting the temporary branch temp
git branch -d temp


Also, make sure to edit the merge commit message so that it does not mention the branch name 'temp' to avoid a wart in the commit history.

Great this is what I wanted, but I'm not sure why temp branch is needed. And can I delete refactor branch at the end too? (I can just work on develop branch after merging it so I don't need it anymore)

And also, If I do rebase instead, wouldn't git do the git rm * on the top of current develop branch which would result the same?
